# Авторизация сессии

Tags: авторизация, php, сессия

Хочу сделать авторизацию на сессиях в PHP. Скрипт ниже, вызывает ошибки:

При авторизации:

> `[17-Aug-2012 14:48:33] PHP Warning:  session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/[...]/index.php on line 37`

При выходе из скрипта: (index.php?logout)

> `[17-Aug-2012 14:49:39] PHP Warning:  session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/[...]/index.php on line 37`
>
> `[17-Aug-2012 14:49:39] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/[...]/index.php on line 42`

И для выхода не перенаправляет на index.php

> header("Location: index.php");

```
    <?php    
function draw_form($bad_login = false) {
     ?>
     <form action="" method="post">
         <input type="text" name="login"></input><br/>
         <input type="password" name="pass"></input>
         <input type="submit" name="submit"></input>
     </form>
     <?php
if ($bad_login)
    echo 'неправильный логин и/или пароль';
}

function check_login($login, $pass) {
     return ($_POST['login'] == 'admin') && ($_POST['pass'] == '565656');
}

session_start();

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {

     $login = $_POST['login'];
     $pass = $_POST['pass'];

     if (count($_POST) <= 0)
         draw_form();
     else {
         if (check_login($login, $pass))
             $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
         else
             draw_form(true);
     }
}

isset($_SESSION['login']) or die();
?>
```

Как можно исправить? Не пойму, в чём может быть дело...

Comment: Сие есть аутентификация...

Comment: Спасибо, за поправку =)) Запишу на корку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session_start()` нужно вызывать до любого вывода в браузер. Попробуйте в самое начало скрипта переместить.

Comment: Я уже пробывал...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте перед стартом сессии присвоить ей имя

`session_name('name');` например.

Comment: PHP Warning:  session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/

Comment: тогда проблема в том что у вас что то выводится до старта сессии

Comment: Ставлю сессию самой первой:
PHP Warning:  session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/[...]/index.php on line 13

Comment: @Factory, почему 13ая строка? 
Или у Вас 12 пустых строк?

Comment: Потому что, там была разметка ))
Спасибо всем за помощь, разобрался...